# How to make a Shell Script behave as if it were a Real User

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, scripting

My goal is to ssh to a server called gateway, and then from there ssh to a server called meerkat. Once I am in meerkat I want to run a script that copies files from a directory in the server to my home machine.

For the sake of simplicity we can assume we only need to do a single ssh jump if that makes answers more clear.

Essentially, if I have some arbitrary bash script testScript.sh on my home computer, how can I have that script be executed on the remote server?

Right now I have tried

```
cat testBashScript.sh | ssh -tt gateway "ssh meerkat \" cat >> testBashScript.sh  && chmod 755 testBashScript.sh && ./testBashScript.sh  \""
```

This creates a very strange output which is not at all what I expect.

Generally, it seems to me that if I can do something by hand in a shell like bash, then I should be able to write a script that "acts" like me and can input to the machine, and respond to output like a real user could.

Are there entierly different ways I need to interface with everything when writing a script, or is there some simple way to accomplish this generally?

If this is not possible, what is a simpler way to backup files on a remote server with a script?

Lastly, if all other questions fail, how can I script effectively when it is so different from being user in a shell environment?

Comment: Why can't you write a normal script and then you `scp` the script to the remote machine. Then `ssh` to that machine and run the script?  Obviously you need to do it in two steps, but same concept applies.  (And yes - it's very painful the other way..).

Comment: Hi Jacob and welcome to unix SE ! Please refrain from asking too many questions at the same time.  You are alll over the place with this post. Select what you perceive as more relevant to your issue and post it with necessary details, such as your _"very strange output"_ or at least reference it with a link to a binned file on a repo of your choice if more than a few lines. So if you captured your _"very strange output"_ is in file `my_output`, do: `cat my_output | /usr/bin/curl -F '\''f:1=<-'\'' ix.io`  assuming you have `curl` or similar installed on your box.

Comment: Try simplifying your one-liner `"ssh meerkat \" cat >> testBashScript.sh  && chmod 755 testBashScript.sh && ./testBashScript.sh  \""`, with: something like: `"ssh meerkat \" bash < <(cat < \"${1:-/dev/stdin}\")\""`.  You might want to escape the string sign too as in `\$`. Not tested with `ssh`.